# How to reach Luton Airport from Watford Junction?

Tags: public-transport, budget, airport-transfer, ltn, weekends

I'm looking for an efficient way to reach Luton Airport from Watford Junction, during the weekend. More exactly, on a Saturday morning. It doesn't matter if it's with the train, bus or even taxi. I would like to know what's the best way taking in consideration the price/time spent. I usually used to take the following route:

Watford Junction - Kenton - Overground (around £1.80)
Kenton - Northwick Park - walk 5 minutes (around 50 calories)
Northwick Park - Finchley Road - Metropolitan  (around £1.80)
Finchley Road - Luton Airport - National Express (around £11)

After my math that would be ~£15.

Comment: I could not find any trips on there currently, but it never hurts to check http://blablacar.co.uk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest would be a taxi / minicab, you're probably looking at something like £30-£40 if booked in advance

Next is the [321 bus from Watford to Luton station](https://www.arrivabus.co.uk/south-east/services/321---sapphire---watford-to-luton/?direction=outbound), then any of the local buses up the hill to the airport. I can't seem to find prices, but it should be under a tenner.

Otherwise, have a play with the [TFL Journey Planner](https://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey) and the [National Rail Enquiries journey planner](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/planjourney/search), and see what they suggests. Looks to be £11.20 if you go via St Albans on the train, or £23.20 via London. Via London would be train to Euston, tube / walk to St Pancras, then Thameslink train to Luton Airport Parkway. Via St Albans is train to St Albans Abbey, walk to St Albans City, the Thameslink train to Luton Airport Parkway,

Either way by train, you want to buy a ticket to Luton Airport. You'll get off at Luton Airport Parkway station (at the bottom of the hill), but your Luton Airport ticket will be valid on the shuttle bus from the station to the airport. If you buy a ticket only to Luton Airport Parkway, you'll need to pay again on the bus. (Well, or walk, it's about 30 minutes walk up a big hill, take the station exit by the Hampton hotel not the station forecourt one)

Comment: For the St Albans route, you should factor in a half hour walk from one station to the other.

Comment: The National Rail Enquiries journey planner already factors in the walk time, though you can almost certainly do the connection on foot quite a bit faster than they think as they have fairly slow walking speeds built into their timings

Comment: I didn't know that, I was talking from personal experience. However, my comment was more in the line of: half hour walk in St Albans, followed by a ten minutes respite in the train before you have to face a daunting half hour climb in Luton, all of this while carrying your luggage. Topple that with all the walking you usually have to do in an airport and by the time you reach your plane you only want a hot water basin to plop your feet in. :-)

Comment: @DiegoSánchez There are perfectly good buses running from Luton Airport Parkway to the airport, from both sides of the station, for anyone who doesn't want the epic slog up the hill!